# How to point to the field in dart without dart:mirrors?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have model

```
class Model {
  int counter;
}
```

now I get a Model object at runtime, so I mark it as dynamic.

```
dynamic model = new Model();

int counter = 3;
```

What would be possible way to do equivalent of

```
 model['counter'] = counter;
```

one thing to mention is that counter from Model is used in the app somewhere, so tree shaking wont remove it.

I am looking for any solution.

```
class Model {
  int counter;

  var counterPath = "any way to reference counter field, so I can give the value to it";

}
```

open to any suggestion or hack :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to implement a mapping between string name and actual field like

```
class Model {
  int counter;

  // reading: print(model['counter']);
  operator [](String name) {
    switch(name) {
      case 'counter':
        return counter;
      default: throw 'Field $name doesn't exist' in $runtimeType'; 
  }

  // writing: model['counter'] = counter;
  operator []=(String name, dynamic value) {
    switch(name) {
      case 'counter':
        counter = value;
        break;
      default: throw 'Field $name doesn't exist' in $runtimeType'; 
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, its a good workaround. I will wait if someone comes up with some others solutions before I mark as correct.

Comment: That's totally fine of course. You can also change the accepted answer at any time later.

Comment: Without reflection this is the best solution.  The only way you might make it nicer is with some code gen tooling to avoid manually writing and maintaining the switch statements.

Comment: I customized this solution. Instead of defining an operator, I enforce implemented interface that has the same function.

Answer (score 3):

I'd not recommend this, as using `model['string']` makes you loose a lot in maintainability.
But if you truly need it, the best way to achieve this is by using code generation.

In your case, [json_serializable](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable) may be a good idea. As it will generate a `toJson` method and a `MyClass.fromJson` constructor ; without having to change your model in any way.

In the end you'd have

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Model extends Object with _$ModelSerializerMixin {
  int couter;
  Model();

  factory Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ModelFromJson(json);
}
```

Which allows you to run the following :

```
final model = new Model()
  ..counter = 42;
final modelJson = model.toJson();
modelJson['counter'] = 43;

final result = new Model.fromJson(modelJson); // counter = 43
```

This may not be the most optimal in term of performances. But it's far less likely to have a bug or require constant edit.

---

That was for the easy solution.

But that's ugly ; please don't do that.
If you have a real use case where you need reflection then instead of loosing all type check ; create a custom code generator.

There are a few awesome toolings for code generators in dart.

Starting with the lower layer [source_gen](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/source_gen) followed by [build](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/build) to name a few.
Dart team created a lot of tools for code generation ; go take a look !

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I am trying to avoid code generation in the dependecy injection package I am writing. So I am looking for this hacks to implement.

Comment: Flutter (dart in general) embrace code generation. And DI is a perfect use case. There are some packages out there that generate everthing needed for DI ; without loosing type check/autocomplete.

Comment: Yeah, I know it does, but I want to make DI that will work without code generation. and then if you want, you can generate code and it will work too, thus removing boilerplate.